# Objective-C, How can we rotate UIAlertViewController to 180 degree

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation, uialertviewcontroller

I am working on application, I need to rotate screen by 180 degree. For this I am using this code in viewDidLoad Method-

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
    {
        // iOS7
        self.navigationController.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4*6);
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationController.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    }
```

It worked for me for ViewController. Issue is that when I try to present alertViewController it didn't work for me. You can see in image-

[image: Output result is here...]

I tried attempts:

```
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:NO completion:^{

            alertController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

        }];
```

also I tried :

```
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:NO completion:^{

                alertController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI*2);

            }];
```

I am using this method to present UIAlertController-

```
-(void) showAlertWithNoAction:(NSString *) message and:(NSString *) title
{
    if ([message isEqualToString:@"" ] || message ==nil) {
        message = @"Some error occured!";
    }

    if([UIAlertController class])
    {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                              alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                              message:message
                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {

                                   }];




        [alertController addAction:okAction];



        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:NO completion:^{



        }];

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```

I need to show alert message on tap Button "Accept" as you can see in screenshot.

Please help to rotate UIAlertViewController as MainVC is rotated.

Comment: Thanks, I already mentioned that I tried but it didn't work for me. I already gone through this link.

Comment: i think you used the presentViewController in before rotated are you called the UIAlertViewController  after the rotation

Comment: can you add some additional code

Comment: Added code. You can see.

Comment: how will you rotate your Main VC

Comment: I have mentioned at very first in question, How am I rotating MainVC. It is working fine. Only issue in UIAlertController. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: your question is not clear for understand

Comment: I have added screenshot, you can see in that screenshot that ViewController is rotated at 180degree. Actually I did using this code self.navigationController.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); You can clearly see that UIAlertController is not as View Controller. I only need to rotate the UIAlertController as I did for ViewController.